# editing a bootstrap template, changing the jarvisWidget header text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, template-engine

Does anyone have experience using jarvisWidgets in a bootstrap template. I'm using a theme from https://wrapbootstrap.com/
and the widgets are pretty simple, however I can't seem to change the headings, and if I use them on different pages they get changed based on what was already in the template - some css overwriting must be going on - but I don't know where to look.

this is strange and seems so simple - I cannot seem to change the header (title) of a chart widget.

looking at the /smartAdmin/DEVELOPER/AJAX_version/#ajax/morris.html file

line 60

```
<header>
    <span class="widget-icon"> <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> </span>
    <h2>Sales Graph</h2>           
</header>
```

one would think that I could change the text "Sales Graph" to "Anything I like" - and that would be that.
However this is not the case!!!!

I can REMOVE the H2 tags, and the text will not show. (as expected)
I can REMOVE the 'widget-icon' SPAN, and the icon will not show (as expected)

HOWEVER

if I change < h2>Sales Graph to < h2>My Graph - the text remains "Sales Graph" on the rendered page

if I implement this graph widget on the dashboard.html page - the text renders as "Live Feeds" (!) regardless of what I text I type.

Answer (score 9):

JarvisWidgets uses [HTML5 LocalStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). Each time you reload your page, it will get settings from `LocalStorage` for each widget specified by their unique `id` attribute. So make sure you do so for each widget. i.e.

`<div class="jarviswidget" id="wid-id-0">`

Also, you can call the method `localStorage.clear();` to clear the storage and reload your HTML changes.

You should check their documentation for more information. :)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

UGH - all this new client side stuff....

It uses local storage - and the cache needs to be cleared to see the changes....

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: This helped a lot. Interestingly, in Chrome, using the settings' various "clear cache" methods didn't work, and I had to manually delete stored data via Chrome's console. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `js` folder. Go to `app.config.js` and change the `localStorageJarvisWidgets` to false. It will turn off the local storage.